# htaccess, mod_Rewrite, cakephp

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cakephp, dreamhost

I've been stuck for a few hours over this. I found lots of information online but nothing that solved my issue.

I'm hosted on Dreamhost with a custom PHP installation (5.2.14).
The site returns a 500 Internal Server Error with this .htaccess file.

It looks like the rewrite rule is also applied to my php.cgi file but I don't know how to avoid that.

My log file shows that there is an infinite loop somewhere "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error".

```
<IfModule mod_actions.c>
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler php-cgi .php
    Action php-cgi /cgi-bin/php.cgi
    </IfModule>

    <FilesMatch "^php5?\.(ini|cgi)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from env=REDIRECT_STATUS
    </FilesMatch>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]   
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

app/.htaccess :

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]    
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
```

And app/webroot/.htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteBase /    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose it *could* be your cgi.  Try something like this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]   
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

You'll also want to make sure there isn't something goofy going on in your app/webroot/.htaccess  It might be helpful to post both here.

Comment: Good idea! But it doesn't work... I added the other htaccess.

Comment: I came across the altered answer as a suggestion for breaking a hard-to-find redirect cycle.  Maybe it will help.

Comment: Brilliant! It solves the issue and the site appears to be fully functional! Can I leave it like that safely?

Comment: Assuming it doesn't break anything I don't see why not.