# .htaccess / mod_rewrite.c : CakePHP application in a subfolder where the root folder hosts a Wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I'd like to deploy my CakePHP-app from localhost to the webserver, but I get `Error 500`.

My Folder structure looks like this (note: the Cake-app is not in the root...). The `.htaccess`-files **(0) - (3)** are according to [this post [SO]:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094090/htaccess-mod-rewrite-cakephp?rq=1), and as this is a CakePHP&Wordpress server, I tried [this advice here, too [SO]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910610/cakephp-application-in-a-sub-folder-and-wordpress-in-root-how-to-modify-htacces?rq=1).
The app is obviously located in the `CAKEAPP`-Folder, where a subdomain `cakeapp.mydomain.com` points at.

```
ROOT
├── .htaccess (0)
├── CAKEAPP
│   ├── .htaccess (1)
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── .htaccess (2)
│   │   ├── WEBROOT
│   │   │   ├── .htaccess (3)
├──{wordpress-files}
```

---

**(0)** .htaccess in the `ROOT` FOLDER

```
    Action php /cgi-php52/php
AddHandler php52 .php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

php_value memory_limit "128M"

#BEGIN Image Upload HTTP Error Fix
<IfModule mod_security.c>
<Files async-upload.php>


</Files>
</IfModule>
<IfModule security_module>
<Files async-upload.php>


</Files>
</IfModule>
<IfModule security2_module>
<Files async-upload.php>


</Files>
</IfModule>
#END Image Upload HTTP Error Fix
```

---

**(1)** .htaccess in the `CAKEAPP`-Folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

**(2)** .htaccess in the `ROOT/CAKEAPP/APP`-Folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

**(3)** .htaccess in the `ROOT/CAKEAPP/APP/WEBROOT`-Folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/webroot
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `│   │   ├── WEBROOT` <- is it really named WEBROOT? if so, just name it `webroot` and that's probably that. In principle there is nothing you need to do to put a cake app in a subfolder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for `mydomain.com/cakeapp`:

**(0)** .htaccess in `ROOT` FOLDER

```
#Action php /cgi-php52/php
#AddHandler php52 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^cakeapp/(.*)$ /cakeapp/$1 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**(1)** .htaccess in the `CAKEAPP`-Folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /cakeapp
 RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
 RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**(2)** .htaccess in the `ROOT/CAKEAPP/APP`-Folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /cakeapp
 RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
 RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**(3)** .htaccess in the `ROOT/CAKEAPP/APP/WEBROOT`-Folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /cakeapp
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two project one main project which is running fine but now i want to run another cakephp project on the same domain.

So you are in the write place this tutorial will help you to run a cakephp on a sub domain

1. First you have change the .htaccess on  /httpdocs/

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ cake_sub_project/app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) cake_sub_project/app/webroot/$1 [L]
   ```

   This two new line needs to add on your main .htaccess file. Here "cake_sub_project" is the sub project

   ```
   RewriteRule    ^$ cake_sub_project/app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) cake_sub_project/app/webroot/$1 [L]
   ```

Now goto your sub folder and make sure you have changed the .htacces on the following directory.

```
    cake_sub_project/
    cake_sub_project/app
    cake_sub_project/webroot
```

2. Need to edit the .htaccess from /httpdocs/cake_sub_project as following

```
    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /cake_sub_project/
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

3. Need to edit the .htaccess from /httpdocs/cake_sub_project/app as following

   ```
      

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /cake_sub_project/app/
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
   ```
4. Need to edit the .htaccess from /httpdocs/cake_sub_project/app/webroot as following

   ```
      

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /cake_sub_project/app/webroot/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
   ```