# CakePHP shows blank page with no errors at remote server

Tags: php, cakephp, centos, cpanel

I have a CakePHP 2.5.1 site hosted on a CentOS dedicated server that have installed CPanel(includes apache, exim, php, and etc) and on this site i have a management area, but for some reason, this area only works properly at localhost, if i upload the site into the remote server it just shows up a blank page.

Obs: all the rest of the site works properly, only the management area that does not work.

Obs²: someday i uploaded the site into another server and the area was working, so i think that the problem might be with the server.

I solicited technician support with CPanel but they are not capable to help me as long they does not know how CakePHP works, but they tried to.

I know that a external links are not recommended to use, btw i have sure that i really cannot reproduce the problem on another place, so there is the link to the blank page: http://www.acheiapartamento.com.br/biz/

Here is the **routes.php** defined (as you can see "/biz/" url pointing to pages controller index):

```php
<?php

/**
 * Routes configuration
 *
 * In this file, you set up routes to your controllers and their actions.
 * Routes are very important mechanism that allows you to freely connect
 * different URLs to chosen controllers and their actions (functions).
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.Config
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */
/**
 * Here, we are connecting '/' (base path) to controller called 'Pages',
 * its action called 'display', and we pass a param to select the view file
 * to use (in this case, /app/View/Pages/home.ctp)...
 */
/* BIZ */
Router::connect('/biz/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'biz' => 'true'));


/* HOME */
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/home', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));

Router::connect('/classificados-home', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'classificados'));
Router::connect('/destaques-home', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'destaques'));
Router::connect('/lancamentos-home', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'lancamentos'));


/* EMPRESA */
Router::connect('/sobre', array('controller' => 'institucionais', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/dicas', array('controller' => 'institucionais', 'action' => 'dicas'));

/* EMPREENDIMENTOS */
Router::connect('/destaques', array('controller' => 'empreendimentos', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/empreendimentos/enviar_contato', array('controller' => 'empreendimentos', 'action' => 'enviar_contato'));
Router::connect('/destaques/:slug', array('controller' => 'empreendimentos', 'action' => 'interna'));
Router::connect('/empreendimentos/:slug', array('controller' => 'empreendimentos', 'action' => 'interna'));
Router::connect('/buscador', array('controller' => 'empreendimentos', 'action' => 'busca'));
Router::connect('/resultado', array('controller' => 'empreendimentos', 'action' => 'resultado'));
Router::connect('/classificados', array('controller' => 'empreendimentos', 'action' => 'classificados'));
//Router::connect('/lancamentos', array('controller' => 'empreendimentos', 'action' => 'lancamentos'));
Router::connect('/lancamentos/enviar_contato', array('controller' => 'lancamentos', 'action' => 'enviar_contato'));
Router::connect('/lancamentos', array('controller' => 'lancamentos', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/lancamentos/:slug', array('controller' => 'lancamentos', 'action' => 'interna'));


/*EMPREENDIMENTOS BAIRROS*/
Router::connect('/bairros/busca', array('controller' => 'empreendimentos_bairros', 'action' => 'busca'));

/*CLIENTE */ 
Router::connect('/blog', array('controller' => 'noticias', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/blog/:slug', array('controller' => 'noticias', 'action' => 'interna'));
Router::connect('/ache-para-mim', array('controller' => 'interesse', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/ache-para-mim/comercial', array('controller' => 'interesse', 'action' => 'comercial'));

Router::connect('/atendimentos', array('controller' => 'atendimentos', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/clientes', array('controller' => 'clientes', 'action' => 'index'));

Router::connect('/meus-favoritos', array('controller' => 'clientes', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/meus-imoveis', array('controller' => 'clientes', 'action' => 'meus_imoveis'));


Router::connect('/cadastre-seu-imovel', array('controller' => 'empreendimentos', 'action' => 'cliente_imovel'));

Router::connect('/faq', array('controller' => 'faqs', 'action' => 'index'));

Router::connect('/pergunte-ao-corretor', array('controller' => 'perguntas', 'action' => 'index'));

/* CONTATO */
Router::connect('/contato', array('controller' => 'contatos', 'action' => 'index'));

Router::connect('/aplicativo', array('controller' => 'aplicativos', 'action' => 'index'));


Router::connect('/cortarimagem', array('controller' => 'empreendimentos', 'action' => 'cortarimagem'));

/** EXPORTAÇÃO **/


/* IMPORTACAO */
Router::connect('/importacao/', array('controller' => 'empreendimentos', 'action' => 'importacao'));
Router::connect('/importacao-imagem/', array('controller' => 'empreendimentos', 'action' => 'importacao2'));

/* BEMORAR */
//Router::connect('/exp-bemorar/:id', array('controller' => 'bemorar', 'action' => 'index'));



/**
 * Load all plugin routes. See the CakePlugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
CakePlugin::routes();

/**
 * Load the CakePHP default routes. Only remove this if you do not want to use
 * the built-in default routes.
 */
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Here is the code of **PagesController.php**:

```php
<?php

/**
 * Static content controller.
 *
 * This file will render views from views/pages/
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.Controller
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('UsersController', 'Controller');
App::uses('BannersController', 'Controller');

/**
 * Static content controller
 *
 * Override this controller by placing a copy in controllers directory of an application
 *
 * @package       app.Controller
 * @link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/pages-controller.html
 */
class PagesController extends AppController {

    /**
     * This controller does not use a model
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $uses = array();

    /**
     * Displays a view
     *
     * @param mixed What page to display
     * @return void
     * @throws NotFoundException When the view file could not be found
     *  or MissingViewException in debug mode.
     */
    public function display() {

    $path = func_get_args();

        $count = count($path);
        if (!$count) {
            return $this->redirect('/');
        }
        $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

        if (!empty($path[0])) {
            $page = $path[0];
        }
        if (!empty($path[1])) {
            $subpage = $path[1];
        }
        if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
            $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
        }
        $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));

        try {
            $this->render(implode('/', $path));
        } catch (MissingViewException $e) {
            if (Configure::read('debug')) {
                throw $e;
            }
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

    }

    public function biz_index() {
        echo "teste";
    }

    public function index() {
        echo "teste";
        $produto = new ProdutosController();
        $this->set('produtos', $produto->Produto->find('all'));
    }

}
```

The same codes work here at localhost, the **phpinfo()** of localhost and my remote server are ALMOST the same, i've checked it.

**Remote phpinfo() (does not works):**
https://drive.google.com/a/unesc.net/file/d/0Byyr3Jl114rReUg2cnhTSTZ2b1E/view

**Localhost phpinfo() (works):**
https://drive.google.com/a/unesc.net/file/d/0Byyr3Jl114rRSTVobzRic2NlWFk/view?usp=sharing

No errors appears on logs and the page is blank so i dont really know what to do, i need to fix that as fast as i can.

Comment: Enable debugging. In your `app/Config/core.php` file set `Configure::write('debug', 2)`;

Comment: it is already set to 2.

Comment: clear cache from  tmp\cache > models, persistent and views folder

Comment: I suggest that you get rid of prefix routing (it's not the intended use) and properly set up CakePHP so that it can run from a subfolder. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265258/htaccess-mod-rewrite-c-cakephp-application-in-a-subfolder-where-the-root-fo) for further information.

Comment: with what proof you can say that? everything that i was learned on the internet about cakephp was using routes, i never saw a cakephp without using this routes on my whole life :p by the way i gave it a try and got many 500 internal server errors...

Comment: @Salines i deleted all the files inside this folders just did leave the "empty" file, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Remote phpinfo() (does not works):  try ```<?php 
echo ini_get('disable_functions');```  to see disabled extensions on your server.

Comment: What you are doing there in your pages controllers `index()` method is highly discouraged! You should never instantiate controllers manually, except for in unit tests! Anyways, to find out what's wrong you'll have to do some debugging, all people here can do is guessing, which is anything but helpful. So go on, insert breaktpoints, being it manually, or using a debugging tool like XDebug or PhpDbg, and figure where exactly things start to break.

Comment: @Salines for some reason when i execute this command i get a blank page with nothing print.

Comment: @ndm it is possible to debug php if the code is remote and on a CentOS server w/CPanel?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are facing is because of the permissions. The bellow link may help you:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#permissions

Comment: changed all folder permissions from 0755 to 0777 and now instead of a blank page i get error 500 internal server error, in all pages of the site

Comment: its the "app" folder that cannot be 0777 or i get the internal server error

Comment: You should not change all folder permissions. You just need to follow the instruction given in the documentation. As of now check the apache error log for any error.

Comment: Also enable the debugging into your application. In your app/Config/core.php file set Configure::write('debug', 2);

Comment: is is already enabled, i did ran the three commands on the SSH shell that i am connected to the server when i was on the directory public_html and nothing has changed.

Comment: Which server do you have?

Comment: I have a dedicated server running CentOS and CPanel(that includes apache php and so)