# Set subdirectory through .htaccess without creating a folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a Cakephp project, that is in the folder `/var/www/html/project/` and that always has to stay in that folder. At the moment I can access the project via `www.example.com/project`. Now I want to modify the .htaccess files, so that project is not reachable at project but e.g. at demo like `www.example.com/demo`.

In Cakephp there exist 3 .htaccess files. I guess another one (Number 0) can solve this problem. But how?

```
var/www/html
├── .htaccess (0)
├── project
│   ├── .htaccess (1)
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── .htaccess (2)
│   │   ├── webroot
│   │   │   ├── .htaccess (3)
```

The original .htaccess look like the following:

1.) **project** folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

2.) **App** folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

3.) **webroot** folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I already watched at [.htaccess / mod_rewrite.c : CakePHP application in a subfolder where the root folder hosts a Wordpress installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265258/htaccess-mod-rewrite-c-cakephp-application-in-a-subfolder-where-the-root-fo), but this didn't helped me out somehow.

Comment: No, not any of those three .htaccess can solve this - because if you request /demo, the web server has no reason to look inside of /project to begin with, so it will not evaluate any .htaccess located there either. This needs to happen in the .htaccess on the root level. `RewriteRule $demo(.*) project$1 [L]` could already work.